# What is the definition of Dynamical mass?

Tags: classical-mechanics, mass, astrophysics, definition, stars

I am looking into Protostars and Dynamical masses. I know as a whole system a protostar has a certain mass, which includes the envelope/accretion disk. However, if I wanted the mass of the protostar or center portion only would that be my Dynamical mass or would the gas/dust from the disk for instance be the dynamical mass? I am having trouble understanding the definition. Or even like in a solar system would the planets be the dynamical mass?